# error accessing dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python / pandas Dataframe and to programming at all, but I can't figure out why I have an error:

I have a Dataframe named closes that have a column named ISP.MI that I need to access to perform operations.

If I run the code:

```
    `print(closes['ISP.MI][0])`
```

I get the correct value.

If I run the code

```
Name = ['ISP.MI']
print(closes[Name][0])
```

I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Name = 'ISP.MI'` is the what you're looking for.

Comment: @JohnGalt is right. In the future make sure you include more code and certainly include the error that you receive. The issues is that you're trying to index a list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, in fact the problem was that python interpret this :
`x = ['ISP.MI']` as a list and not as a string.

```
x = 'ISP.MI'
```

and

```
x = x[0]
```

work to solve my question :)